# node.js: Send raw data of Uint32Array

Tags: node.js, tcp

The following node.js code converts a string to Uint32 array.
But when I tried to send the array I got:

ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE

Can you tell why ?

When I tried to send:
Buffer.from(arr32).buffer

I got only the LSByte in each 32 bits word.

Thank you,
Zvika

```js
function tcpConnect ()
{
    // Send a connection request to the server.
    client.connect({
        host:'localhost',
        port:5100
      });

    client.on('connect',function(){
        console.log('Client: connection established with server');
        
    });

    client.on ('close', ()=>{
        console.log ("TCP close");
        setReconnectInterval ();
    });

    client.on ('error', function () {
        console.log ("TCP error");
    });
}

 tcpConnect ();
 let data = "3405655469, 7, 1036, 0, 1, 2,...,255";
 let arr = data.split (',');
 var arr32 = new Uint32Array(arr);

 client.write (arr32);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the fastest way ?

```js
var arr32 = new Uint32Array(arr);
    var arr8 = new Uint8Array (arr32.length * 4);
    let j=0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr32.length; i++)
    {
        arr8[j++]=arr32[i] & 0xFF;
        arr8[j++]=(arr32[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8;
        arr8[j++]=(arr32[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
        arr8[j++]=(arr32[i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
    }
```

Comment: `const arr8 = new Uint8Array(arr32.buffer)`